# Render problem with a glass material and the Archipack addon

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, shaders, glass, archipack-add-on

I struggle with a more or less realistic environment for my prototype model of my desk.

So first the preview, with Cycles (left side). When I render the scene, the door glass is white and not transparent as it should be (the window glass is transparent).

I used the archipack add-on.

Someone got an idea?

[image: Image of my problem]

Comment: May be there is an object hidden in viewport but visible on render.

Comment: okay, thats nearly embrassing. Yes, the original wall is in the door hidden in viewport but nur in rendermode... Thanks!